# GIMP - export to PNG changes the color completely (from RGB to GRAY)

Tags: gimp, export, png

Could somebody please help me to export an image from GIMP to PNG?

I have an RGB image in GIMP.

[image]

When I export the image to JPG I got the expected results:

[image: Exported to JPEG]

However, when exporting to PNG Orange color will be changed to GRAY:
[image: PNG export]

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Image is in the PNG mode. Here is the Export PNG dialog which I'm using:
[image: PNG export dialog]

Layers dialog is here:
[image: Layers dialog]

Comment: Hi Jirka I edited your question to add the images, it's better than using an external link to google drive.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your PNG Save options dialog? And is the image color-indexed?

Comment: I can't replicate the problem.  My guess would be you altered something in the PNG export dialog. Press the "Load Defaults" button in the PNG Export dialog to reset it and try again.

Comment: I guess there is a Color Option in the Export option...change it from Grayscale to RGB

Comment: There is no setting in the PNG export dialog which should cause this to happen. If you find one which does, or a combination of the available ones, please tell us.

Comment: Jirka, can you show us a full screenshot of the GIMP UI, including the layers dialog?

Comment: I have uploaded xcf file to https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2-SMQrgs3ombGlPdzU0ZC1STms along with "Export to PNG" dialog and Layers dialog. The image is in the RGB mode.

Comment: In the layers panel, make sure you select something. Since your image has only one layer, just click its name. Then export as PNG. I have no idea whatsoever why (and therefore I'm reluctant to add this as an answer), but it seems having nothing selected in the layers panel, causes the image to be exported as greyscale without alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So - thankfully you linked GIMP's full screenshot. The problem is that what is the active drawable you have when exporting to PNG is not one of the image layers - as you can read on the status bar on the botton, the active drawable is the "selection mask copy".

That is a channel on the channels tab - in GIMP you have one "drawable" object active at a time - drawables can be image layers, layer masks, or channels. Only Layers are color capable, all the other are grayscale drawables - and when one of those is active, that drawable is exported to disk, instead of a merged compose of the visible layers.

The "selection mask copy" mask is created when you pick the `Select-> Save to Channel` menu option, and made the active drawable. Just click on you layer preview icon on the layers tab to make it active again - and then PNG export will work as expected.

(And to see/reproduce the problem, open the "channels" guide and click on "selection mask copy" before a trial export from there).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, you have saved my day!  It's interesting to note that Export to JPG is not affected by this - I can see why is that but it's very confusing when Export to JPG gives completely different result than the export to PNG. In your opinion, should we contact GIMP developers to at least give a warning in such situations?

Comment: Yes - the behavior should be consistent - you can open a bug for GIMP at http://bugzilla.gnome.org - - or if you want some more direct contact with the developers, you should use iRC - channel #GIMP on irc.gimp.org