# GIMP - export to PNG changes the color completely

Tags: gimp, export, png

I have problem very similar to [GIMP - export to PNG changes the color completely (from RGB to GRAY)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/91875/gimp-export-to-png-changes-the-color-completely-from-rgb-to-gray).
i.e. colors in exported images are changed to gray. What I am doing wrong?
here https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/7ehp7ny8yosnocy4l6bp1/h?rlkey=5dmp0ps2coga6spshqzecicmw&dl=0 are example files these "*-1.*" are indexed while two others are not.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Your XCF is in Indexed colour mode (not RGB). However, exporting your XCF to PNG appears to work just fine. [see example](https://i.imgur.com/2a30ohK.png). What version of GIMP are you using?  IF nothing else works for you, try this: convert the document to RGB, then export as PNG.

Comment: Note that the other question you linked to seems to suggest this may have been a bug.  It may have been fixed in more recent versions. Check you are using the most up to date version of GIMP. Currently 2.10.34

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your exported PNG isn't gray... if you zoom in there are orange pixels, and the color map contains orange colors (including the main color for the text, #ffaa00 as #102). Only the `test` layer is changed. Furthermore the transparent strip on the right is partially filled with a grayish color (#7e7e76). Can you show the export dialog? What Gimp version is this? Did you try to merge the layer before export?

Comment: xenoid - you mean "export-test-1.png" is orange?
Billy Kerr - I suspect that problem is https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/9933

Comment: @kjonca - I can't reproduce that issue either. I'm using GIMP 2.10.34 and Win 11.

Comment: @BillyKerr `export-test-1.png` has orange pixels, it is not all gray. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/WzBFkDk.png)

Comment: @xenoid - yeah something's clearly up. Have you any thoughts as to what might have caused it? I'm at a loss unfortunately.

Comment: @BillyKerr Nope. Complete mystery to me.

Comment: To be precise:
1. take file export-test.xcf (this is rgb mode)
2. export - efect should be similart to export-test.png (no problem)
3. change mode to indexed (effect should be similar to export-test-1.xcf)
4. export with "automatic pixelformat"  orange turns gray (similar to export-test-1.png)
Did you do similar steps and got orange text?
Maybe problem is with version (2.10.34 under linux only?)